# Pivot table based on groupby in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like this:

```
customer_id | date     | category
1           | 2017-2-1 | toys
2           | 2017-2-1 | food
1           | 2017-2-1 | drinks
3           | 2017-2-2 | computer
2           | 2017-2-1 | toys
1           | 2017-3-1 | food

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dt = dict(customer_id=[1,2,1,3,2,1],
              date='2017-2-1 2017-2-1 2017-2-1 2017-2-2 2017-2-1 2017-3-1'.split(),
              category=["toys", "food", "drinks", "computer", "toys", "food"])) 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dt)
```

ues my new columns and one hot encoding those columns, I know I can use `df.pivot_table(index = ['customer_id'], columns = ['category'])`.

```
>>> df['Indicator'] = 1 
>>> df.pivot_table(index=['customer_id'], columns=['category'],
                   values='Indicator').fillna(0).astype(int)                                                             
category     computer  drinks  food  toys
customer_id                              
1                   0       1     1     1
2                   0       0     1     1
3                   1       0     0     0
>>>
```

I also want to group by `date` so each row only contains information from the same date, like in the desired output below, id 1 has two rows because two unique dates in the `date` column.

```
customer_id | toys | food | drinks | computer 
1           | 1    | 0    | 1      | 0        
1           | 0    | 1    | 0      | 0
2           | 1    | 1    | 0      | 0
3           | 0    | 0    | 0      | 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may looking for `crosstab`

```
>>> pd.crosstab([df.customer_id,df.date], df.category)                                                                                                                
category              computer  drinks  food  toys
customer_id date                                  
1           2017-2-1         0       1     0     1
            2017-3-1         0       0     1     0
2           2017-2-1         0       0     1     1
3           2017-2-2         1       0     0     0
>>>
>>> pd.crosstab([df.customer_id,df.date],
                df.category).reset_index(level=1)                                                                                           
category         date  computer  drinks  food  toys
customer_id                                        
1            2017-2-1         0       1     0     1
1            2017-3-1         0       0     1     0
2            2017-2-1         0       0     1     1
3            2017-2-2         1       0     0     0
>>>
>>> pd.crosstab([df.customer_id, df.date], 
                df.category).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)                                                                                
category     computer  drinks  food  toys
customer_id                              
1                   0       1     0     1
1                   0       0     1     0
2                   0       0     1     1
3                   1       0     0     0
>>>
```

Comment: Is it possible in this scenario to get individual row vectors by each date? I.e. the date should be at the top left corner and other columns and corresponding row remains same. Maybe by looping over each date

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your frame is called `df`, you could add an indicator column and then directly use `.pivot_table`:

```
df['Indicator'] = 1

pvt = df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'customer_id'],
                     columns='category',
                     values='Indicator')\
        .fillna(0)
```

This gives a dataframe that looks like:

```
category              computer  drinks  food  toys
date     customer_id                              
2017-2-1 1                 0.0     1.0   0.0   1.0
         2                 0.0     0.0   1.0   1.0
2017-2-2 3                 1.0     0.0   0.0   0.0
2017-3-1 1                 0.0     0.0   1.0   0.0
```